# Unable to POST JSON with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have some old jQuery code that I'm trying to migrate to AngularJS. That jQuery code looks like the following:

```
var vm = { name: getName(), description: getDescription() };
$.ajax({
  url: "https://mydomain.com/order/place",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(vm),
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: order_Succeeded,
  error: order_Failed
});
```

I know that code works. Now, I'm trying to do it in AngularJS. In my attempt, I'm trying:

```
$scope.sendOrder = function() {
  $http.post(u, $scope.getModel())
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('all good');
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(status);
      console.log(data);
    })
  ;
};

$scope.getModel = function () {
  var vm = {
    name: getName(), 
    description: getDescription()
  };
  return vm;
};
```

When the above code gets executed, I get a 404 error. I have no idea why. I keep staring at it and it looks correct to me. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Debug the backend? What are the headers being sent back

Comment: When I do console.log(headers), I get: function (name) {
    if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

    if (name) {
      return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
    }

    return headersObj;
  } order.js:71
GET

Comment: That feels like a bank end issue, as you are being answered with a 404 and the post is being executed. Is the url variable (u) set properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, do this before making the call:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
```

Longer answer, read this [PHP focused article](http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/) and this [ColdFusion focused article](http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2013/10/1/Calling-a-ColdFusion-CFC-from-AngularJS).

If that doesn't help, first verify the URLs to make sure you don't have a typo in the AngularJS app.  Then try u sing a network sniffer to  review the packet differences between the two.